# How should a Twisted AMP Deferred be cancelled?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have a Twisted client/server application where a client asks multiple servers for additional work to be done using AMP. The first server to respond to the client wins -- the other outstanding client requests should be cancelled.

`Deferred` objects support `cancel()` and a cancellor function may be passed to the `Deferred`'s constructor. However, AMP's `sendRemote()` api doesn't support passing a cancellor function. Additionally, I'd want the cancellor function to not only stop the local request from processing upon completion but also remove the request from the remote server.

AMP's `BoxDispatcher` does have a `stopReceivingBoxes` method, but that causes all deferreds to error out (not quite what I want).

Is there a way to cancel AMP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way, presently, to cancel an AMP request.

You can't cancel AMP requests because there is no way defined in AMP at the wire-protocol level to send a message to the remote server telling it to stop processing.  This would be an interesting feature-addition for AMP, but if it were to be added, you would not add it by allowing users to pass in their own cancellers; rather, AMP itself would have to create a cancellation function that sent a "cancel" command.

Finally, adding this feature would have to be done very carefully because once a request is sent, there's no guarantee that it would not have been fully processed; chances are usually good that by the time the cancellation request is received and processed by the remote end, the remote end has already finished processing and sent a reply.  So AMP should implement asynchronous cancellation.